# Callback not being triggered by Graph UI calls (AS3)

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, facebook-as3-api

I've got a Flash application working with the AS3 Graph API as far as Facebook opening up the requested dialogues (purchase, post, invite). Unfortunately, these calls to Facebook.ui never seem to result in the corresponding callback method being triggered.

For example, the below method successfully opens the Facebook post dialogue, but the _fbPostResponse() method never gets fired in response.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

```
// Sample Code - This method should post a link to the user's wall
// The _fbPostResponse method should be invoked by Facebook when this action is complete.
function post(link:String, pic:String, name:String, caption:String, desc:String):void {
 trace("Post to wall");
    var params:Object = {
      link:link,
      picture:pic,
      name:name,
      caption:caption,
      description:desc
    }
  Facebook.ui("feed", params, _fbPostResponse);
}

// The _fbPostResponse method should be invoked by Facebook when this action is complete.
function _fbPostResponse(response:Object, fail:Object):void
{
  trace("Post response!");
}
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you by any chance got this to work?

Answer (score 0):

The Callback function for Facebook.ui takes only one parameter. Try the following:

```
// The _fbPostResponse method should be invoked by Facebook when this action is complete
function _fbPostResponse(response:Object):void
{
  trace("Post response!");
}
```